# Python program not running as expected

Tags: python, linux, sqlite

When I run it, nothing happens, but it doesn't throw any errors, what it should do is prompt the user for the alum numbers to pull from the db, then move these albums from the db to a portable device. Any ideas why it is not running???

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3
import os
import shutil

get_albums = []

def makedatabase(dbname):
    #dbname = 'mp3_database.db'

    if not os.path.exists(dbname):
        print"Creating new database", dbname, "and tables", "in dir", os.getcwd()

        connection = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE albums (music_location TEXT, genre TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, album_number int)""")
            connection.commit()
            connection.close()
            print"\nDatabase creation complete proceeding to program"


    else:
        print"Database name already exists!!!!!"




def album_input(selection):
    while True:
        response = int(raw_input(selection))
        get_albums.append(response) 
        if response == 0:
            print 'continuing'


def process_albums():

    for num in get_albums:

        connection = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        connection.text_factory = str
        album_results = cursor.execute("SELECT genre, music_location, artist, album FROM albums where album_number =?", (num,))
        (genre, music_location, artist, album) = album_results.fetchone()
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()


        print genre
        print album
        genre_dir = os.path.join(dest_dir, genre)
        artist_dir = os.path.join(genre_dir, artist)
        album_dir = os.path.join(artist_dir, album)

        if not os.path.isdir(genre_dir):
            os.makedirs(genre_dir)

        if not os.path.isdir(artist):
            os.makedirs(artist)

        if not os.path.isdir(album):
            os.makedirs(album)

        songs = []

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(music_location):
            for fname in files:
                songs.append(fname)
        sorted_songs = songs.sort

        for test in sorted_songs:
            finished_song = os.path.join(music_location, test)
            new_finished_song = os.path.join(artist, test)
            shutil.copyfile(finished_song, new_finished_song)




#main

dest_dir = raw_input("Enter the destination directory to move files to: ")
start_database = makedatabase("mp3database.db")
get_selections = album_input("Enter album numbers, Press 0 to process: ")
start = process_albums
finished = raw_input("Press Enter to exit")
```

Comment: You need `process_albums()` instead of `process_albums`

Comment: I fixed that, and I also took the print 'continuing' statement out and placed a break statement there, now I'm getting that global name dbname is not defined

Comment: `sorted_songs = songs.sort` is assigning   sorted_songs  to a reference to the `list.sort` method, even if you correctly  called it you would be setting it sorted_songs  equal to None, .`list.sort()` is an inplace method so just call it on the list and iterate over the list or else use `sorted_songs = sorted(songs)`

Comment: Now getting TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do the list.sort, I tried sorted_songs = list.sort(songs)  still got NoneType object is not iterable

Comment: okay the sorted songs worked, but still not copying the files... Any ideas?

Comment: You are not adding the full path, you need to append `os.path.join(root, fname)` and  forget `music_location`

Comment: I changed that, but it is still not copying the files, only creating the dirs, also can you tell me how to get it to not process the 0 that is being entered to terminate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Process albums is a function, so to call it, you need the parentheses. Replace process_albums by process_albums().
2. You have used dbname is process_albums(). You cannot use this, as it is only defined in the scope of the makedatabasename() method. You could either use dbname as a global variable, or set it as a parameter in process_albums.

Comment: I fixed both of these problems, and corrected the sort, but it is still not copying files???

Comment: It is correctly creating the directories now, just not moving files. In addition it seems to be trying to process the 0 as a part of the array

Comment: In case anyone is interested, got the whole thing working, only problem now is it is slow as syrup, any thoughts on how to make it speed up?

Comment: Try testing the speed of your functions. It could be slow because of the sql queries.

Comment: megadarkfriend I have absolutely no clue how to do that, but it is painfully slow, upwards of 2 hrs to move 140 albums to device. I really need to speed this thing up. I can post entire code if you would like to see it???

Comment: Take a look at the timeit module. It allows you to measure execution time of small code snippets